# Room and spaces not visible in forge viewer

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are trying to view the rooms and spaces  (3D) in Forge Viewer
Tried all this troubleshooting given in this URL: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-assets.viewer#troubleshooting

Our objective is to identify the rooms and spaces and highlight them.

Please let us know if there is anything we can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a way to generate rooms and spaces from your Revit models. The solution is to use what is known as **master views** which are basically 3D views that are generated for each phase of the Revit model.

You will need to use the Model Derivative API to translate your model to SVF and when using this API, you will need to include a parameter known as **generateMasterViews**.

You can learn more about this process by going through this blog post: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces